# I can't get a background image to repeat vertically with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I cant get my background image to repeat vertically using CSS and HTML. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div style="stack">
<img src="http://i.imgsafe.org/370409f.png" style="background-repeat:repeat-y;
width:120px;height:100px;alt="sunflower"> &nbsp
</div>
width:120px;height:100px;alt="sunflower"> &nbsp
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
.stack {
background-image:url(http://i.imgsafe.org/370409f.png)
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's kind of unclear what your code is trying to do, you have broken HTML and CSS in just about everything. You should run your code through a validator and it will tell you everything that is broken. But here's the general concept. Mainly just change `style="stack"` to `class="stack"` and then put your CSS in a CSS file and remove all of the broken inline `style` attribute stuff.

```css
.stack {
  background: url(http://i.imgsafe.org/370409f.png) 0 0 repeat-y;
  height: 1000vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="stack">
</div>
```